# ASP.Net Upload Source Code to Web Server or Upload VS2010 Published Files

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, web, publish

I am developing ASP.Net MVC websites. Currently I publish (using VS210) the site and upload the published code, bin file, views, css etc.

The only issue I have with this is that the only place I then have the actual source code is on my local machine and backup drive. I tend to work from various places and pull others in to work on projects from time to time and we do not have the infrastructure to synch it all at the moment.

Having the source code on the server can actually be quite useful to me.

But is there any problems with doing this? I presume there is no performance issue as it will be compiled anyway, but what about security?

The web config file tends to store the DB connection - but this is present on the server regardless of source upload or published upload.

Any input appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Deploying the build outputs to the server is definitely the correct thing to do. What you are looking for is generally called [source control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source_control). That will let you keep a database of your source, including revisions. It is the first step to enlightened development. You really shouldn't leave home without it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I understand source control. But I am looking for why deploy build output - what is the issue with source being on the server?